# Ignore git show errors

Tags: git

I'm writing a script that calls `git show` a bunch of times. Sometimes, it calls `git show $COMMIT:$FILE` on `$FILE` that doesn't exist in `$COMMIT`. This prints an error to the terminal. Normally this would be the right thing, but for the moment, I'm not bothered about this. (The script works fine even when this happens). So is there a way to just suppress errors from git? I couldn't find a flag…

Comment: What OS are you using? Maybe you can redirect the error output

Comment: @dusan Yes I can do `./script 2>/dev/null` but I was wondering if there was a way to do it from inside the script?

Comment: `git show $COMMIT:$FILE 2> /dev/null` ?

Comment: @dusan Oh yeah. For some reason it just didn't occur to me to do that. But am I right that there's no `git` flag to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no `git show` flag that allows that.

Just redirect the error output inside your script:

```
git show $COMMIT:$FILE 2> /dev/null
```